# Quelle est la différence entre les prépositions "dans" et "en" (et "à") ?

Tags: prépositions

par exemple :

> en 5 minutes
>
> > dans 5 minutes
>
> en classe
>
> > dans la classe
>
> à la maison
>
> > dans la maison
> >
> > en la maison

quelle est la différence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - En cinq minutes : cela se fait en cinq minutes (durée).
> - Dans cinq minutes : cela sera commencé dans cinq minutes (délai).
>
>   ---
> - En classe : cela se passe dans une classe, quelle que soit la salle de classe (type de lieu).
> - Dans la classe : cela se passe dans la classe des élèves concernés (lieu de l'action).
>
>   ---
> - À la maison : *Les devoirs sont à faire à la maison* (c'est à dire hors de la classe, mais ils peuvent être fait dans un autre endroit, la maison étant le lieu privilégié pour un élève)
> - Dans la maison : *À l'intérieur de la maison* (intra muros)
>
>   ---
> - En la maison : *Se déplacer en la maison de...* est parfois utilisé par la Justice pour indiquer que le tribunal s'est déplacé sur les lieux du crime ou du délit. 
>     C'est une tournure vieillotte, plutôt utilisée dans les contes  : *Il était une fois, en la maison de la bonne fée ...*

N.B. : Rester prudent avec cette dernière formulation, elle n'est pas d'un usage courant, les recherches Internet ne trouvent pas d’occurrence immédiate.

Elle est plutôt utilisée avec *ce(s)* :  "En ces lieux, et même en ce monde, vous ne trouverez pas ce que vous cherchez !".

Comment: Merci beacoup. mais, excuses-moi. je n'ai pais comprìs le case "En la maison "

Comment: *en classe* est plutôt une question de l'événement que du lieu, non? IL me semble que cela veut plutôt plutôt dire "durant un cours scolaire, peu importe le lieu".

Comment: @Circeus un cours scolaire peut aussi être *en amphi* ou *au stade*, la notion de lieu est importante, et c'est un 'type' très particulier lorsqu'il s'agit d'une *classe* (autrefois munie d'une estrade et d'un tableau noir)

Comment: @cl-r Ce que je veux dire, c'est qu si un prof me dis que quelque chose s'est produit *en classe*, le détail important, c'est que ça s'est produit *pendant qu'il/elle donnait un cours*. L'endroit où ce cours se donnait n'est pas pertinent.

Comment: @Circeus Oui : dire *en classe*, ou *pendant un cours* est équivalant (surtout si c'est le prof' qui parle d'un incident qui s'est passé dans une de ses classes) ; mais *en classe* n'est *dans la cour*, ce n'est pas le même type d'endroit, et les comportements ne sont pas les mêmes   dans ces espaces différents.

Comment: @cl-r Mais la comparaison que moi et dragonmnl faisons est entre *en classe* et *dans la classe*. Je ne vois d'où tu tiens que quelqu'un ait fait quelque allusion que ce soit à *dans la cours*.

Comment: @Circeus Je répond à : " *en classe* est plutôt une question de l'événement que du lieu, non? ", le *cours* est un événement, la *classe* est un 'type de lieu', l'événement (le cours) aurait pu se passer *au stade* (autre type) ; en revanche *dans la classe* est un lieu précis et unique, quel que soit le cours.

Comment: Si un événement survient durant le cours d'éducation physique, on n'en parlera pas en disant "En classe", par exemple. De même, si un élève frappe un autre entre 2 cours dans le local de cours, cela se passe "En classe", même si aucun cours n'était donné à ce moment, il s'agit donc bien d'un lieu, pas d'un événement... L'événément serait plutôt exprimé "durant le cours de ..."